# Only display first error in gsp

Tags: grails, grails-validation

I'm performing inline validation on fields as the user tabs between them.
A problem occurs when there is more than one error against a field i.e both errors are shown.
I only want to show one error (The first one for arguments sake).

Is there are different tag to deal with this?

```
<jqvalui:renderError for="title">
    <g:eachError bean="${objInstance}" field="title"><g:message error="${it}" /></g:eachError>
</jqvalui:renderError>
```

Thanks

Comment: hope you will get your answer or may be idea to solve here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233969/grails-gsp-break-out-of-geach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially you just have to use the errors themselves instead of using the tags provided for you.

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${objInstance}" field="title">
    <g:message error="${objInstance.errors.getFieldErrors("title")[0]}" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's like a hack but if no exact solutions...
Consider adding a flag or a counter and set/test it inside the loop:

```
<g:set var="isErrorShown" value=""/>
<g:eachError bean="${objInstance}" field="title">
    <g:if test="${!isErrorShown}">
        <g:message error="${it}"/>
        <g:set var="isErrorShown" value="TRUE"/>
    </g:if>
</g:eachError>
```